# Synapse notebook input validation deprecation warning

Tags: scala, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to do some input validation in a Synapse notebook running in Scala mode like this:

```
if (! someInputParameter.startsWith("/")) {
    error("Parameter someInputParameter should start with a forward slash (/).")
}
```

But I receive the following error:

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
```

I'm guessing there is a newer way of doing this which does not trigger the deprecation warning? I don't know how to run the notebook in a mode with the `-deprecation` switch.  I imagine it would be similar in Azure Databricks but haven't test yet.

Comment: I am interested to see other methods of input validation and error handling in Synapse Notebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sys.error` instead, ie

```
if (! someInputParameter.startsWith("/")) {
    sys.error("Parameter someInputParameter should start with a forward slash (/).")
}
```